# How to change meta contents by using javascript

Tags: meta-tags

I am trying to change content for meta tag by using javascript. Below code is not working with me:

```
metatags = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
```

Please give your suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`metatag1 = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[0]`, if meta tag that you wanna change is the first in your page, if you want to change the second one use `metatag2 = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[1]`, then use this

`metatag1.setAttribute("content", "new content")`;

But you better get elements by name like

```
metatagDescription = document.getElementsByName("description")[0],
```

(of course if you are sure that there are not any other elements with e.g. 'description' name)
 to know what meta tag you are gonna change, I think, it is more reliable, rather than base on meta tags order on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you used **jquery** you could simply use `$("meta")` and perform stuff you want on it.
**Chainably**.